# Dual Check on Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, lookup

I have the following list of data on an Excel sheet:

[image: Data]

On column "B" I have a list of logins, and on columns "C-D-E" a list of tasks that the person performs.

Then, I have another list on which I'll select a login linked to a Process. I need the code to say "TRUE" or "FALSE" depending on two thinks:

1. First, it has to check if the login is in the previous list
2. If so, it has to check if the process is one of the Proc 1-2-3 for that login

If both options are happening, the answer should be FALSE, and it should be TRUE if the login is on the list but the process is not right (if the login is not on the list, nothing should happen, or at least the result is irrelevant).

[image]

Right now I have the following code:
[image]

I don't know how to change the green lookup array for the second "MATCH" formula, to check it on the login one (if the login would be "miguel" instead of "rosa", that array should be: C5:E5).

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this [link](https://www.exceldemy.com/fill-color-in-excel-cell-using-formula/), how to change color using formula in excel.

Comment: Sorry @Surya, I can't see how that is usefull to my answer. Could you expand a little bit? :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to post an answer but I think you have misunderstood the question. Maybe read the question again? You can change or delete your answer if you want. The question is basically asking how to write an Excel function to do something.

Answer (score 0):

```
=NOT(OR(H5=INDEX(Sheet11!$A$2:$D$5,MATCH(G5,Sheet11!$A$2:$A$5,0),{2,3,4})))
```

- `INDEX(MATCH...` returns the line matching the login; and with the column argument being the array constant `{2,3,4}`, just those three columns will be returned.
- Then check if any of those entries match the process.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately does not work, if you try for example "rosa" with process "cubis". It only works with the first one

Comment: @MiguelGutiérrezdeAntón What do you mean "`It only works with the first one`"? `rosa` and `cubis` returns `FALSE` which is what you specified.  What do you expect?

Comment: @MiguelGutiérrezdeAntón If your problem is that your login is only in the first cell (`G5` in the example in my answer), and the rest of the login cells are empty but you want those extra rows to refer to `rosa`, then just change the reference to `G5` to be an absolute address.